# How to create Redis Conditional Bean?

Tags: spring, redis

I need to create ***RedisTemplate*** bean in java config.

If redis configuration (redis server info) not found then create default redis bean with empty cache.

Can you please suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you enable/disble your redis module?

Comment: I have created RedisTemplate bean in my Appconfig.java.
If RedisConfig.properties available in resources then its working fine, But if I remove the property file then it obviously throws bean creation exception. So I need to remove redis dependency on application startup

Answer (score 1):

If redis server is not running, you need to implement a cache error handler which redirects to the original method that was to be called, if the data wasn't cached. Following error handler should do the trick :

```
@Component
public class RedisCacheErrorHandler implements CacheErrorHandler {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
    log.info("Unable to get from cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCachePutError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key, Object value) {
        log.info("Unable to put into cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheEvictError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        log.info("Unable to evict from cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheClearError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache) {
        log.info("Unable to clean cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```